# how to convert the view rows into schema in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a view in sql with dynamic columns like

```
id   name     col1             col2               col3
1     a       value1           value2             value3
```

i need output like

```
col_name      values            result
name          a                name : a
col1          value1           col1 : value1
col2          value2           col2 : value2
col3          value3           col3 : value3
```

i have tried multiple things but unsuccessful..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` to unpivot the data:

```
select v.*,
       concat(name, ': ', value) as result
from t cross apply
     (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), ('col3', col3)
     ) v(name, value)
```

Comment: @skzac . . . Columns are not dynamic in SQL.  They are quite well defined in a table.

Comment: By definition it can't be dynamic, @skzac , as you are using a `VIEW` against a table, and neither a `TABLE` nor a `VIEW` can return dynamic data as you can't use dynamic SQL in their definitions.